# XY slider controller grid for HTML forms jQuery / Javascript for web and mobile web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is there a XY slider controller grid for HTML forms jQuery / Javascript function / code somewhere that works for ordinary and mobile web (iOS, android)? And if there isn't how can such a controller be made? 
[image: draft of such a controller]

Answer (score 2):

*2 years later...*

I was looking for the same yesterday and found this:

https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Kontrol

Demo: http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/kontrol/

It works great. This unanswered question shows up high in Google results, so I just thought I'd post.